# Can I use Botium for mobile browser?

Tags: automation, chatbot

> I want to automate chat bot on mobile browser? do botium provide support for i?

Answer (score 0):

Botium supports UI testing with Selenium WebDriver - see [this Botium in a nutshell-article](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-6-e2e-testing-with-botium-box-9bd8acdf5a70). You can just connect it to an Appium-Server instead of a Selenium Server and it will work.

Botium Box supports out-of-the-box device clouds like Saucelabs and Experitest, with a wide range of desktop as well as mobile browser applications.